Angular - 6x5 table
I just don't know how to make this work. I want to generate a 6x5 table, with horizontal and vertical headings:
table
here are the data structures:
ListaCzynnikow {
  nazwa: string;
  waga: number;
  poziomyCzynnika: PoziomCzynnika[];
}

PoziomCzynnika {
  poziom: string;
  etykieta: string;
  wartosc: string;
}

I just have no idea how to do this

you can use a (mat-table)[https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview] or tr``th tags in html or div with nested @for loops

I imagine you have an array of ListaCzynnikow  more or less like
listaCzynnikow=[
  {
    nazwa: 'Zasieg',
    waga: 30,
    poziomyCzynnika: [{ poziom: 1; etykieta: 'Pojedincy..', wartosc: '0,30'},
                      { poziom: 2; etykieta: 'Kylkunastu..', wartosc: '0,60'},
                      ...]
  },
  {
    nazwa: 'Czas occziak',
    waga: 25,
    poziomyCzynnika: [{ poziom: 1; etykieta: '<1h', wartosc: '0,25'},
                      { poziom: 2; etykieta: '<8h/1-8)', wartosc: '0,50'},
                       ...]
  },
  ...
]

You can use some like
<table>
  <thead>
    <!--the head is an unique row with the element-->
    <tr>
      @for(head of ['','1','2','3','4','5'];track $index){
        <td>{{head}}</td>
    <tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!--the body have so may rows as your array ListaCzynnikow -->
    @for(row of listaCzynnikow;track $index){
      <tr>
         <!--the first column is the nazwa and the waga-->
         <td>
           <div>
             {{row.nazwa}}{{row.waga}}
           </div>
         </td>
         <!--the next ones are the values of the poziomyCzynnika-->
         @for(cell of row.poziomyCzynnika;track cell.poziom)
         {
            <td>
               <div>
                  {{cell.etykieta}}{{cell.wartosc}}
               </div>
            </td>
         }
      <tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>

well, instead of a simple <div>{{row.nazwa}}{{row.waga}}</div> and a simple <div>{{cell.etykieta}}{{cell.wartosc}}</div> replace to look better the cell
